# Google Maps geocoding API ZERO_RESULTS example

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

My code is having an error handling when ZERO_RESULTS output is given by GoogleMaps API. When writing my unittest for that part of the code I was already having an example of a string that was giving a ZERO_RESULTS error message. However it looks that google fixed it.

So the question... can somebody provide me an string that is providing a ZERO_RESULTS output from GoogleMaps Geocoding?

All questions I googled with the error seem to be fixed, so will be nice to find a "robust" error one.

Comment: I do not see as too broad. I am just looking for an string, a simple answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to trigger a ZERO_RESULTS response in Geocoding API, I would suggest sending a request that tries to find an inexistent postal code in some country applying a components filtering instead of address string. For example, let's try to search postal code 12345 in Sweden:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A12345%7Ccountry%3ASE&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Or the same request in the Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#in_postal_code%3D12345%26in_country%3DSE%26options%3Dtrue

I hope this helps!